# Microsoft Graph API for office 365 usage reports is not working for Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-edge

I am trying to run Office 365 usage reports in Microsoft Graph using Graph API Explorer in Edge browser(44.18362). This call is not returning any data. Same call is getting succeeded when we run graph explorer in chrome/IE browser.
Issue is active only with edge browser. 
Sample api : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsDeviceUsageUserDetail(period='D30')

[image]

Comment: I tested the Graph api explorer in Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 I got InvalidAuthenticationToken from your sample api but when I tested it with preview data then it worked fine. https://i.postimg.cc/3wvzB9S2/111.gif Can you please try to check on your side whether preview data working fine or not? Also try to check the console to see whether there is any other error message or warning. Let me know about your testing results.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT . Other apis work fine. Problem is with reports api that i mentioned and edge browser. It needs Reports.Read.All permission to run. Once you assign these permissions then only we can test. It am not sure if we can test this api with preview data

Comment: Can you please try to provide the detailed steps for generating that specific report and making this test? I will try to refer the step for reproducing the issue. It can help to make the test accurately. Thanks for your understanding.